# .Net Architecture challenge: The Change-prone Frankestein Model

Tags: .net, architecture

Good Morning SO!

We've been scratching our heads with with this interesting scenario at the office, and we're anxious to hear your ideas and approaches:

1. We have a database, whose schema is
   prone to changes -lets call it
   **Prony**-. (is used to store configuration parameters for
   embedded devices. so if the embedded
   devices guy need a new table,
   property or relationship for the
   model, he should be able to adapt
   the schema in a easy way -happens so
   often- ).
2. **Prony** needs a web interface to
       create/edit its data (a set of simple CRUDs would be enough).
3. We have another database containing
       data that also need to be loaded to
       the devices, after making some
       transformations - lets call this one
       **Oddy**- (this data it's generated by an already existent
       administrative web application).
4. Finally we have **Tracy**, a server that communicates our DBs and our embedded devices.
   She should to auto-adapt herself, to our dbs schema changes and serialize the data to the devices.

Nice puzzle, don't think so? : )

---

**Our current candidate:**

- **Rady: The fast**

  Lets create some views in
  **Prony** that make the data transformation from **Oddy**. then
  use ***DynamicData*** (or some RAD
  tool) to create/update a simple web
  interface for **Prony** (so he can
  even consult the transformated data
  from coming from **Prony** : ). About
  **Tracy**, she will need to be recompiled
  to update her DB schema (***Entity framework*** should work) and use ***Reflection*** to explore recursively the schema and serialize data.

  Cons:

  - We would have to recompile **Tracy** and the **Prony**'s web interface.

**What do you think of the candidate?**

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with a data model that is constantly changing after product release is to use the [EAV Database Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model), in whole or in part, of your database design. The EAV structure adds rows rather than columns or tables and allows for much less frequent schema changes (or none at all.)

It does come with its own set of caveats of course, such as the need to often pivot the data, but they can be managed. There are plenty of EAV dbs out there in production.

**Performance note:** People often worry about the performance of EAVs. i've have a number of EAVs with the EAV tables running well over 10 million records. Reads, inserts, updates and deletes are fine. The trouble comes in when you start doing heavy reporting on such a data structure. In your case you're storing config info for devices. That's not innocuous or trivial but I would say that that part of the db sounds like a great candidate for EAV since your reads and writes are going to be limited and i'm guessing that your reporting needs simple.

Comment: Hi Paul,
Hey that's a nice idea, so schema changes could be done without recompiling : ) +1

Comment: Absolutely right. You just have to make sure that your code is as flexible as the persistence model. E.g. do you need to deal with new entities or will you only be adding/modifying the attributes of a set of known entities?

Comment: Hi Paul, in this case, Yes, we would also need to create new entities. nice point +1 again : ). I'm considering Umbraco for this (is already EAV and has a nice web interface too : ). we would just need to find out a way to integrate Umbraco with external DBS (Oddy). what do you think?

Comment: Does Oddy need to be a database? Seems like this is where you would put a web service which presents a config API and pulls the data from Prony? Or is Oddy a some flavor of compact db running on mobile devices? Btw, EAV is just fine for small dbs as well. i just wouldn't try OLAP-style reporting with it.

Comment: Hi again Paul, Oddy is already a DB, but we can expose a web service API. great idea : ) -we're ashamed to discover someone of the team proposed it since the start, how could we ignore it? lol-. EAV would be fine, this is just a config parameters db. thanks again : ) +1